# Putting Font Awesome Icons in Kendo TabStrip tabs as images

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to utilize FA to put icons beside each of my tab names but not sure how to go about this, I understand there is ImageUrl but not sure how to use that with a font.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
 .Name("tabstripMain")
 .Items(tabstripMain =>
 {
    tabstripMain.Add().Text("<i class='fa fa-anchor'></i> Summary")
 })
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: you might have to add them after creating the tabstrip with jQuery/JavaScript:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/edEVu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a easier way to do this.

Make sure you have the font awesome stylesheet referenced in your page.

then here is the razor syntax to add tabstrip with the font awesome icons:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("tabstrip")
          .Items(tabstrip => {
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Area Chart")
                  .SpriteCssClasses("fa fa-area-chart")
                  .Content(@<text>
                        <div style="height:300px"> <h3>Area Chart</h3></div>
                    </text>);
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Bar Chart")
                  .SpriteCssClasses("fa fa-bar-chart")
                  .Content(@<text>
                    <div style="height:300px"> <h3>Bar Chart</h3></div>
                </text>);
          })
```

)

Notice that i am using SpriteCssClasses method to set the CSS class for the tabstrip icons. SpriteCssClasses takes a string array also if you want to specify a list of classes. In this example i have just given the complete class "fa fa-area-chart" as a single string which is valid too.

Here is the output of the above code:

[image: Kendo UI TabStrip with Font Awesome Icons]

Hope this helps.